# Trying to make my social links stay still when hovering over them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Whenever I hover over my social links on my website, they shift to the left. This started happening after I got the scrollToggle function in jQuery to work, so I feel like it might have something to do with that. Does anyone know how I can make it so they can stay still when hovered over? Thanks in advance.

```
jQuery code:

$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#slide").hide();
        $("#contact").click(function() {
           $(".socials").show();
           $("#slide").slideToggle("slow");
     });      
  });
```

Rest of the code/website example (Click Contact, and then hover over any of the social links. You should notice that it shifts over to the left.)
https://jsfiddle.net/Lc2ob45x/

Answer (score 2):

Remove the following statement from your CSS:

```
div:hover {
  width: 300px;
}
```

[Working version.](https://jsfiddle.net/5s3Lm0jg/)